# Store Ganache GUI Blockchain on Windows

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle, ganache

Is there a way to store Ganache in memory blockchain into a folder? I saw that we have ganache-cli --db which allow us to do this, but I'm interested if I can do the same thing with Ganache GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ganache UI does not have a parameter which supports the `--db` parameter offered by ganache-cli. However, it is possible to specify this location by manually building and running Ganache UI on your machine (note: this is a bit of a work-around)

Follow [these steps](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache#getting-started) for cloning the ganache repo and installing the necessary npm packages.

Then, within the cloned repo, navigate to the `src/chain/chain.js` file. Search for the line of code which starts the ganache-core server. It should look like this:

```
server = ganacheLib.server(options);
```

Now, add a line of code before this to specify the database path:

```
// This option will tell ganache-core where to instantiate the database.
options.db_path = "C://my_example_db_folder"; 
server = ganacheLib.server(options);
```

Finally, all you have to do is run the application from the source code by utilizing the `npm start` command. (You may need to also install `electron-forge` via `npm install -g electron-forge`.) You will now have Ganache UI running with the database pointed to the folder you have designated.

As a note, Ganache utilizes [LevelDB](https://github.com/google/leveldb) and the [levelup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/levelup) JavaScript library to persist and interact with the data. Also note that you may need to blow away the contents of the folder when re-starting Ganache UI.

Comment: Is there a way to restore DB after re-starting? I don't wanna lose all my blockchain after restart.

Comment: @EmersonMicu, not that I am aware of off-hand. The idea behind Ganache is to create a non-reusable dev sandbox for Ethereum. I'd suggest locally running a single-node via geth or parity if you want something reusable.